# How to get geojson WFS to run faster

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, geojson, wfs, performance

I use geoserver + openlayers. The problem is that WFS geojson layer has over 10000 objects and when i'm trying to see the map through web-browser it works very slow and laggy. How can i speed it up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fast and responsive maps don't try to have 1000s of objects being drawn in the browser. Use a WMS layer where the hard work is done on the server and all the client has to do is display pictures of the map (which it is good at).